# macOS x управление яркостью висит на клавишах f14 f15. Где они?

Tags: macos, mac, apple

По умолчанию управление яркостью в настройках горячих клавиш стоит на f14 f15. Я слабо представляю как эти клавиши нажать.

http://joxi.ru/D2P8vgKspvo1G2

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH7115?locale=ru_RU&viewlocale=ru_RU

Где искать клавиши f14 f15?

Comment: Они находятся на удлиненной клавиатуре. На короткой это F1 и F2. Возможно, у вас настройки от длинной клавиатуры остались. В любом случае, можно поменять настройки на свои.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На расширенной клавиатуре Apple Magic Keyboard присутствуют клавиши вплоть до F19. Вам стоит переставить управление яркостью на f1-f2, как оно стоит по умолчанию на компактной клавиатуре.